# What causes a finally block to execute too soon?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch-finally

I have a try-catch-finally block that looks like so:

```
ResultSet rs;
PreparedStatement ps;
Connection conn;
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        ** execute SQL query **
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
} finally {
    ** close result set **
    ** close prepared statement **
    ** close connection **
}
```

I've verified that my ArrayList list had 534 elements in it.  The problem is that the finally block to close everything is executing after the first occurrence of my for loop which causes the next occurrence to throw an exception because the connection is now closed.

I've never encountered a situation where the finally block executes before the try block has completed.  What could cause this scenario?

Comment: Could you include more of your original source code?  Obfuscating the query itself if you'd like.  But more context would help.

Comment: Could it be that your first iteration throws exception? That would explain it.

Comment: You're probably re-using a non-reusable object.

Comment: `catch(Exception e){ throw e}` what useful! :rolleyes:

Comment: Attaching the stack trace would be also useful.

Comment: The finally block does not execute before the try block completes. To figure out what is going on will require seeing more code.

Comment: Post the exception and stack trace please.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, what is happening is that `finally` is working as expected.  The short explanation is that a `finally` block is executed *no matter how* the `try` block terminates.

In your example, and based on what you have said, the most likely scenario is as follows:

- the loop body throws some exception,
- the exception is caught and rethrown, and
- the `finally` block is then executed.

The `finally` block will NOT be executed before the `try` block "terminates", so your theory that the `finally` block is *causing* the loop body to fail is not correct.

Reference:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Answer (score 0):

Without more source I would guess that you are not committing your transaction.

If you switch your connection to not auto-commit and then forget to commit your transaction it may **seem** like your `finally` block is executing before your queries when in fact they are merely awaiting committal before executing.

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html#commit_transactions) for a discussion.